# Can the efficiency of an algorithm be modelled as a function between input size and time?

Tags: algorithm, theory

Consider the following algorithm (just as an example as the implementation is obviously inefficient):

```
def add(n):
    for i in range(n):
        n += 1
return n
```

The program adds one number with itself and returns it. Now the efficiency of an algorithm is [sometimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency#Theory) modelled as a function between the size of the input and the number of primitive steps the algorithm has to compute. In this case, the input is an integer, n, and as n gets increased the number of steps necessary to complete the algorithm also increase (in this case linearly). But is it true that the size of the input increases? Let's assume that the machine where the program is running is representing integers in 8 bits. So if I increase the hypthetical input 3 for example to 7, the number of bits involved remains the same: 00000011 -> 00000111. However, the steps necessary to compute the algorithm increase. So it seems like that it's not always true that algorithmic efficiency can be modelled as a relation between input size and steps to compute. Could somebody explain to me where I go wrong or if I don't go wrong, why it still makes sense to model the efficiency of an algorithm as a function between the size of the input and the number of primitive steps to be computed?

Answer (score 1):

Let `S` be the size of the input `n`. (Normally we'd use `n` for this size, but since the argument is also called `n`, that's confusing). For positive `n`, there's a relation between `S` and `n`, namely `S = ceil(ln(n))`. The program loops `n` times, and since `n < 2^S`, it loops at most `2^S` times. You can also show it loops at least 1/2 * 2^S times, so the runtime (measured in loop iterations) is `Theta(2^S)`.

This shows there's a way to model the runtime as a function of the size, even if it's not exact.

Whether it makes sense. In your example it doesn't much, but if your input is an array for sorting, taking size as the number of elements in the array does makes sense. (And it's typically what's used for example to model the number of comparisons done by different sort algorithms).

Comment: Does that mean that we define a different relation between `S` and every kind of input? That is, do we define `S` differently depending on what kind of input (array, integer, string, etc.) we have and that we not simply equate `S` with the number of bits of the input (or some other quantity)?

Comment: Yes, size and runtime can be defined in lots of different ways, and not just in terms of bit size and clock time. For example comparison sorts use the number of elements of the list, and the number of comparisons as the "size" and "runtime". If you look at more abstract complexity theory (eg: study of NP problems), the size and runtime is more consistently defined.